# Opening Ubuntu partition in Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-7

I'm curious, is it possible to be logged on to my windows 7 partition, then from there also use Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, say through a window or something along those lines? Because I have all of my things I need on Windows such as Microsoft Word, iTunes, etc. However, I need to do processes in Ubuntu which can take hours to complete. Basically, I would like to be able to do things in Windows while sort of running Ubuntu in the background. I've already dual booted my machine and everything runs properly.

I would want to do this with my computer as is, without creating a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

No, to the best of my knowledge that is not possible without creating a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine). There would need to be something like a [hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) in the bios. You could certainly (theoretically) create such a hypervisor (perhaps, even into the [bios](http://www.coreboot.org/Welcome_to_coreboot)), but it isn't available on commodity hardware and that would necessitate a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, it is possible to read your Linux partition under Windows through a software but I don't think you can do what want except by using virtualization and this case, you have Ubuntu in virtual machine before.